# JComponent not appearing

Tags: java, awt

I'm trying to create a super simple component, and it's not appearing.

Component class:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JComponent;

public class Player extends JComponent{
    
    public Player() 
    {
    
    }
   
    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {  
        g.setColor(Color.green);  
        g.fillRect(40,40,150,150);  
    }  

   
}
```

Panel Class im adding it to:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Rectangle;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Game extends JPanel{

    public Game() 
    {
        this.setBackground(Color.yellow);
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500,500));
        Player p = new Player();
        
        this.add(p);
        
    }
    
}
```

And the JFrame:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Launcher {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Key Collector Demo");
        
        frame.add(new Game());
        frame.pack();
        
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(frame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        
    }

}
```

The only thing showing up is the yellow background.
JFrame and JPanel are working fine; this problem consistently happens to me when building jcomponents. What am I missing?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `Player` ought to be a plain Java getter/setter class that maintains the location of the player.  Your `JPanel` is responsible for all drawings.  Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section.  Pay particular attention to the [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) section.

Answer (score 0):

Coordinates that you are using to draw a component are defined in the space of that component.

If you do this:

```java
public void paint(Graphics g)
{
    g.setColor(Color.green);
    System.out.println(getSize());
    g.fillRect(40,40,150,150);
}
```

You will see that at the moment it is attempted to get drawn its size is `1x1`. So drawing it from `40,40` obviously takes it out of the visible area of the component.

Now change the method to:

```java
public void paint(Graphics g)
{
    g.setColor(Color.green);
    System.out.println(getSize());
    setSize(45, 45);
    g.fillRect(40,40,150,150);
}
```

Now you can see small filled rectangle. This is because you forced the size to be `45x45` and now there are 5 pixels to show in the space of the component while the remaining part is still out of the area.

Comment: Do not set the size in paint()

Comment: It's just for the sake of demonstration

Answer (score 0):

Do not assume the Player panel to have a fixed size.
For a first test your paint method could look like this:

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {  
    g.setColor(Color.green);  
    g.fillRect(0,0,getWidth(),getHeight());  
}
```

The next problem is that the component probably has no size or position. Add a LayoutManager to your panel and add the component:

```
public Game() {
    this.setBackground(Color.yellow);
    this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500,500));
    this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    Player p = new Player();
    this.add(p, BorderLayout.CENTER);
}
```

With that, your player might take the full space and you see green instead of yellow. Play around with the LayoutManager and the player's preferredSize.